# How to do drag and drop for multiple user-created buttons?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my app, the user presses a button which opens a dialogue prompt with multiple inputs. The information is then used to fill out the name of a new button to be created, as well as determine a part of its function.

I want the user to be able to drag the buttons they created anywhere they want on the screen. onLongClickListener (and onClickListener for that matter) expects me to already know some information about the /specific/ button I'm trying to listen for. I want to know how to say, essentially, "listen for a long click on any button with 'draggable' as its tag" or something to that effect.

Comment: You can use library from the Github

Comment: @Ticherhaz Which library?